# iPhone - dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier usage

Tags: iphone, objective-c, optimization, uitableview

I'm working on a iPhone app which has a pretty large UITableView with data taken from the web, so I'm trying to optimize its creation and usage.

I found out that `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` is pretty useful, but after seeing many source codes using this, I'm wondering if the usage I make of this function is the good one.

Here is what people usually do:

```
UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];

if (cell == nil) {
  cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];

// Add elements to the cell
return cell;
```

And here is the way I did it:

```
// The cell row
NSString identifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cell %d", indexPath.row]; 

UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];

if (cell != nil)
  return cell;

cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:identifier];
// Add elements to the cell
return cell;
```

The difference is that people use the same identifier for every cell, so dequeuing one only avoids to alloc a new one.

For me, the point of queuing was to give each cell a unique identifier, so when the app asks for a cell it already displayed, neither allocation nor element adding have to be done.

*In fine* I don't know which is best, the "common" method ceils the table's memory usage to the exact number of cells it display, whilst the method I use seems to favour speed as it keeps all calculated cells, but can cause large memory consumption (unless there's an inner limit to the queue).

Am I wrong to use it this way? Or is it just up to the developer, depending on his needs?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

The purpose of `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` is to use less memory.  If the screen can fit 4 or 5 table cells, then with reuse you only need to have 4 or 5 table cells allocated in memory even if the table has 1000 entries.

In the second way there is no reuse.  There is no advantage in the second way over just using an array of table cells.  If your table has 1000 entries then you will have 1000 cells allocated in memory.  If you are going to do that you would put them in an array and just index the array with the row number and return the cell.  For small tables with fixed cells that may be an reasonable solution, for dynamic or large tables it is not a good idea.

Comment: You're right about the fact that with my method an array could do the job.
Would ~100 cells represent a 'too' large amount of memory allocated at once?

Comment: Well, I changed for the common method (which is complicated when a row has many subviews), and besides lower memory consumption, scrolling overall seems smoother, I'm not sure why.
Thanks for the advice anyways!

Comment: @progrmr   ... thanks...  for clearing the concept.. its really nice... i was also doing same mistake.. :)

Comment: That's not entirely correct. The reason is that a copy of a UITableViewCell (with all its subviews) is more quickly made than an entirely new instance of it. The part about memory usage is taken care of by the fact that cells are released when they are not longer visible. Dequeuing (= copying from template objects) cells just speeds up the process of cell creation. So, it's not about memory, but about processing time and CPU resources used (affecting battery life etc.). You don't save any live memory space at all - cells are still separate objects.

Comment: @manmal That is about memory too. Cells which go off screen are not released but rather reused for cells which became visible.

Answer (score 19):

As for cell identifier- Instead of just using "cell" for the identifier, and instead of using a unique identifier like the OP, could you use a "type-identifier"?  For example, if my table had 3 types of cells- one with a very complicated sub-layout, one with just `Style1`, and one with `Style2`, I should identify those three all separately and then just rebuild them if dequeue comes up `nil`.

For example:

```
-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath{
    NSString* ident = @"";
    if(indexPath.section == 0) ident= @"complicated";
    if(indexPath.section == 1) ident= @"style1";
    if(indexPath.section == 2) ident = @"style2";

    UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:ident];

    if(cell == nil){

       if(ident == @"complicated"){
          cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:ident] autorelease]; 
         // do excessive subview building
       }
       if(ident == @"style1"){
          cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyle1 reuseIdentifier:ident] autorelease]; 
       }

       if(ident == @"style2"){
          cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyle2 reuseIdentifier:ident] autorelease]; 
       }


    }
    if(ident == @"complicated"){
       // change the text/etc (unique values) of our many subviews
    }
    if(ident == @"style1"){
      [[cell textLabel] setText:@"Whatever"];
    }
    if(ident == @"style2"){
      [[cell textLabel] setText:@"Whateverelse"];
    }

    return cell; 
}
```

(This code probably won't run because I wrote it here, but hopefully you get the idea. )

I don't think Apple would have created the whole reusable cell idea with identifiers if they wanted all the identifiers to be `"cell"`, don't you think?

Comment: In your case I'd use an identifier for each cell layout. Which means one for your "complicated" cells, one for the "style1" cells and maybe a third for style2 cells, if their subviews differs from style1 ones.
In the case dequeue returns nil, add the cell's subview with tags (defined in an enum or something), and then initialize them. In the case dequeue returns a cell, simply retrieve subviews using tags and change them.
Separating your code in one method for each section would be nice too :)

Answer (score 13):

The documentation that helped me understand why the idiomatic way (the one you described first) works best was [UITableViewCell class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html) section on the `initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:` method.

The `reuseIdentifier` subsection reads:

> You should use the same reuse identifier for all cells of the same form.

And the "Discussion" subsection reads:

> The reuse identifier is associated with those cells (rows) of a table view that have the same general configuration, minus cell content.

These statements make it clear to me that the idiomatic way to use `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` inside of your implementation of `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` for your `UITableViewDataSource` creates one cell object for each *visible* row regardless of the total number of rows available.

Answer (score 4):

I think the first one is the best (and as you said common) way to implement a `UITableView`.
With your second way there will be memory allocated for every new cell which is displayed and no memory will be reused.

Comment: Well memory will be reused if the user scrolls down and then scrolls back up... Or anytime the tableView accesses a cell which was displayed once then hidden.

Comment: Sure, but there will be a memory footprint for every cell that was ever displayed and not only for the 4-5 cell that are currently displayed.
I've had a similar problem with annotations for the map. Switching to an constant identifier brought a noticeable increase of performance.

Comment: Then I guess it's up to me... Would it be better to cache any data I use to create the cell rather than the cell itself?

Answer (score 1):

`UITableView` internally uses a cell with an identifier as a "Template". So the next time you (read as table) try to deque, it just creates a new cell but using the stored object as template. Hence you still have to update its UI to reflect the cell contents as per context.

This also means that the `UITableView` is doing the memory management of the cells for us, per se. In theory, there will be only so many `UITableViewCell` objects as many as the visible cells. But practically, there might be a couple more waiting to be memory released.

This basically saves memory big time, esp in scenarios where you have 1000 cells.

On any portable device where memory is at a premium, we should defer the allocation of any memory to the last possible moment and release it the moment its job is done. `dequeAndReusing` a cell achieves this and does it pretty well.

On the other hand, if your cell is a customized cell, then we might most probably load a nib and extract from it.
If this is the case, you can either use an identifier to deque OR you can load it from the nib. There is no difference in the procedure.

The only difference could be in the load time. Allowing the Table view to create a new cell using the identifier cell as template ***could*** be slightly faster than loading from nib but it is hardly noticeable and depends on the context.

Comment: Custom cells are also managed by the tableView's memory queue system, as long as they have an `Identifier` set.

Answer (score 0):

To distinguish cell from other cells you can use tag property of the cell or if you are using the custom cell then its very easy through introducing any new property to custom cell while subclassing `UITableViewCell`.

Even though after all these you are stuck and still need to get cell, then you can try following code

`UITableViewCell *cell = [self cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]`

whereas it should be avoided upto extent since it produces the copy of cell but do not return the existing cell whereas the contents will be of same values.