# Why we use the cellIdentifier?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, static, identifier

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath  {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier  ];
    if(cell == nil){
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
    cell.text = [[views objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"title"];
    return cell;
}
```

Why we use the CellIdentifier here and why is it static?

Answer (score 6):

The idea is that the table view doesn't necessarily destroy a cell after it has been used but can recycle it to improve performance. The identifier is used to get the correct cached cell back and not that of another table view. You can even use several identifiers for the same table view if you, for example, have two different cell types that you need all the time.

Imagine to have a cell that consists of a label and an image view. When the cell is initialized, the cell view needs to be created, the label needs to be created and the image view needs to be created. Now every cell of that type looks the same, they only differ in content. So instead of doing this setup all over again every time, an unused cell is sometimes returned where you only fill in the new content.

Comment: In which scenario this if cell will be nil                               if(cell == nil){
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

Comment: You first call `[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];`. If the table view still has an unused cell it can give you that and all you need to do is configure it. But if it doesn't have one (for example because the table is asking you to generate a cell for the first time) then you need to create it.

Answer (score 3):

Static variable will be constructed only once and it avoids memory creation all the time when ever cellforrowatindexpath method is called.it's lifetime will exist through out that file as it is local variable whereas for global static its life time will be existed through out the application

Answer (score 1):

`CellIdentifier` is a way to tag `tableViewCells`. This is so that `uitableView` can know which `uitableviewcell` to pull out when it needs to reuse it.

Answer (score 0):

The cell recycling was already explained in a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2928873). Static variables are “global” for the particular .m file, they are shared between all the instances of the class. That makes sense, as this string is just an identifier – having a separate instance of the same string for each instance of the class would be a waste.

Answer (score 0):

You use a cell identifier like a tag to identify the cell when you try and reuse one by dequeueing it.

It's static because this way you only define it once but it is shared across all objects of the class within this method.