# tableview use of dequeuereusablecellwithidentifier

Tags: ios, ios6, uitableview

i am new in iPhone Please tell me anyone use of  dequeuereusablecellwithidentifier in tableview.
Also tell me without using  dequeuereusablecellwithidentifier how to create cell in tableview??

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2928873/iphone-dequeuereusablecellwithidentifier-usage) is the same question already asked, having solution, **I just typed "dequeuereusablecellwithidentifier" on google**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The best part of using **dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier** is that using this you can re-use your cells.

Imagine if your table has 1000 entries. Now, if for each entry a table cell would be created then for 1000 entries, 1000 tableview cells and memory allocation for 1000 tableview cells.

App will be slowed down or would crash if the entries goes beyond 1000.

When we use, **dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier**, the tableView just creates exactly the number of cells based on your table height and cell height.
Suppose, if it shows 4 cells in the tabelView and rest you can see by scrolling, then memory for only 4 cells would be allocated at any given point of time.

Now, when you will scroll the tableView, it will re-use the same cell but will change the cell content (data) based on your data source.

Hope this clears your doubt.

Adding a cell without using **dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier**

Code

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] init];
    cell.textLabel.text = @"Test";
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: can u tell me how to create cell without using dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier??

Comment: i have added that code in my main answer.