# Overlapping Table cells-content

Tags: iphone, uitableview, ios7

recently I discovered a really annoying bug:

the content of two cells  are mixed up in one cell
I have 16 cells data to display on scrolling the previeously existing cell data get overlapped with current data to be displayed

```
#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 100;
}



- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{

    // Return the number of sections.
    if (flag == NO) {
        return 10;
    }


    return [ytdRate count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return 1;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }



    if (flag == NO) {

    b1Lab1=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20,2,200,40)];

    // NSString *stri = [title objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    b1Lab1.text=[[sortedArray mutableArrayValueForKey:companyNam]objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    b1Lab1.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    b1Lab1.numberOfLines = 0;
    b1Lab1.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:13];
    [cell addSubview:b1Lab1];

    b1Lab2=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(222,12,80,20)];
    NSString *st = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"YTD %@%%",[[sortedArray mutableArrayValueForKey:ytd]objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]];
    b1Lab2.textAlignment=NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    b1Lab2.text=st;
    b1Lab2.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    b1Lab2.numberOfLines = 0;
    b1Lab2.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:13];

    NSString *tem = [[sortedArray mutableArrayValueForKey:ytd]objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
//    NSArray *testItems = [tem componentsSeparatedByString:@"%"];
//    
//    NSDecimalNumber *value = [testItems objectAtIndex:0];

    float tempr = [tem floatValue];
    if(tempr <0){
        b1Lab2.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"val_red_80x20.png"]];
    }
    else{
        b1Lab2.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"val_green_80x20.png"]];
    }

    [cell addSubview:b1Lab2];

    b1Lab3=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20,35,180,20)];
    NSString *st1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Net Asset Value Per Share"];
    b1Lab3.text=st1;
    b1Lab3.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:13];
    [cell addSubview:b1Lab3];

        b1Lab8=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200,35,95,20)];
        b1Lab8.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
        NSString *st10 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[sortedArray mutableArrayValueForKey:netVal]objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]];
        b1Lab8.text=st10;
        b1Lab8.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:13];
        [cell addSubview:b1Lab8];

    b1Lab4 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20,49,90,50)];

    NSString *st11 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"1 YR: %@%%",[[sortedArray mutableArrayValueForKey:oneYear]objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]];
    b1Lab4.text=st11;
    b1Lab4.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    b1Lab4.numberOfLines = 0;
    b1Lab4.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:13];
    [cell addSubview:b1Lab4];

    b1Lab5=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(115,49,90,50)];

    NSString *st12 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"3 YR: %@%%",[[sortedArray mutableArrayValueForKey:threeYear]objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]];
    b1Lab5.text=st12;
    b1Lab5.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    b1Lab5.numberOfLines = 0;
    b1Lab5.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:13];
    [cell addSubview:b1Lab5];

    b1Lab6=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(210,49,90,50)];

    NSString *st13 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"5 YR: %@%%",[[sortedArray mutableArrayValueForKey:fiveYear]objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]];
    b1Lab6.text=st13;
    b1Lab6.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    b1Lab6.numberOfLines = 0;
    b1Lab6.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:13];
    [cell addSubview:b1Lab6];

    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    }
    else if(flag == YES)
    {
        b1Lab1=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20,2,200,40)];

        // NSString *stri = [title objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
        b1Lab1.text=[companyName objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
        b1Lab1.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
        b1Lab1.numberOfLines = 0;
        b1Lab1.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:13];
        [cell addSubview:b1Lab1];

        b1Lab2=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(222,12,80,20)];
        NSString *st = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"YTD %@%%",[ytdRate objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]];
        b1Lab2.textAlignment=NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        b1Lab2.text=st;
        b1Lab2.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
        b1Lab2.numberOfLines = 0;
        b1Lab2.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:13];

        NSString *tem = [ytdRate objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
        //    NSArray *testItems = [tem componentsSeparatedByString:@"%"];
        //
        //    NSDecimalNumber *value = [testItems objectAtIndex:0];

        float tempr = [tem floatValue];
        if(tempr <0){
            b1Lab2.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"val_red_80x20.png"]];
        }
        else{
            b1Lab2.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"val_green_80x20.png"]];
        }

        [cell addSubview:b1Lab2];

        b1Lab3=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20,35,180,20)];
        NSString *st1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Net Asset Value Per Share"];
        b1Lab3.text=st1;
        b1Lab3.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:13];
        [cell addSubview:b1Lab3];

        b1Lab8=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200,35,95,20)];
        b1Lab8.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
        NSString *st10 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [netAsset objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]];
        b1Lab8.text=st10;
        b1Lab8.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:13];
        [cell addSubview:b1Lab8];



        b1Lab4 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20,49,90,50)];

        NSString *st11 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"1 YR: %@%%",[oneYearValue objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]];
        b1Lab4.text=st11;
        b1Lab4.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
        b1Lab4.numberOfLines = 0;
        b1Lab4.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:13];
        [cell addSubview:b1Lab4];

        b1Lab5=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(115,49,90,50)];

        NSString *st12 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"3 YR: %@%%",[threeYearValue objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]];
        b1Lab5.text=st12;
        b1Lab5.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
        b1Lab5.numberOfLines = 0;
        b1Lab5.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:13];
        [cell addSubview:b1Lab5];

        b1Lab6=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(210,49,90,50)];

        NSString *st13 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"5 YR: %@%%",[fiveYearValue objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]];
        b1Lab6.text=st13;
        b1Lab6.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
        b1Lab6.numberOfLines = 0;
        b1Lab6.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:13];
        [cell addSubview:b1Lab6];

        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    }

    [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];

    return cell;
}
```

Do you have any idea how such a behavior can occur?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this..

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

[[cell viewWithTag:111]removeFromSuperview];
[[cell viewWithTag:222]removeFromSuperview];
[[cell viewWithTag:333]removeFromSuperview];
[[cell viewWithTag:444]removeFromSuperview];
[[cell viewWithTag:555]removeFromSuperview];
[[cell viewWithTag:666]removeFromSuperview];
[[cell viewWithTag:777]removeFromSuperview];

if (flag == NO) {

    b1Lab1=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20,2,200,40)];

    // NSString *stri = [title objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    b1Lab1.text=[[sortedArray mutableArrayValueForKey:companyNam]objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    b1Lab1.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    b1Lab1.numberOfLines = 0;
    b1Lab1.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:13];
    b1Lab1.tag = 111;
    [cell addSubview:b1Lab1];

    b1Lab2=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(222,12,80,20)];
    NSString *st = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"YTD %@%%",[[sortedArray mutableArrayValueForKey:ytd]objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]];
    b1Lab2.textAlignment=NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    b1Lab2.text=st;
    b1Lab2.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    b1Lab2.numberOfLines = 0;
    b1Lab2.tag = 222;
    b1Lab2.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:13];

    NSString *tem = [[sortedArray mutableArrayValueForKey:ytd]objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    //    NSArray *testItems = [tem componentsSeparatedByString:@"%"];
    //
    //    NSDecimalNumber *value = [testItems objectAtIndex:0];

    float tempr = [tem floatValue];
    if(tempr <0){
        b1Lab2.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"val_red_80x20.png"]];
    }
    else{
        b1Lab2.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"val_green_80x20.png"]];
    }

    [cell addSubview:b1Lab2];

    b1Lab3=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20,35,180,20)];
    NSString *st1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Net Asset Value Per Share"];
    b1Lab3.text=st1;
    b1Lab3.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:13];
    b1Lab2.tag=333;
    [cell addSubview:b1Lab3];

    b1Lab8=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200,35,95,20)];
    b1Lab8.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
    NSString *st10 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[sortedArray mutableArrayValueForKey:netVal]objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]];
    b1Lab8.text=st10;
    b1Lab8.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:13];
    b1Lab2.tag=444;
    [cell addSubview:b1Lab8];

    b1Lab4 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20,49,90,50)];

    NSString *st11 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"1 YR: %@%%",[[sortedArray mutableArrayValueForKey:oneYear]objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]];
    b1Lab4.text=st11;
    b1Lab4.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    b1Lab4.numberOfLines = 0;
    b1Lab4.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:13];
    b1Lab2.tag=555;
    [cell addSubview:b1Lab4];

    b1Lab5=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(115,49,90,50)];

    NSString *st12 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"3 YR: %@%%",[[sortedArray mutableArrayValueForKey:threeYear]objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]];
    b1Lab5.text=st12;
    b1Lab5.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    b1Lab5.numberOfLines = 0;
    b1Lab5.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:13];
    b1Lab2.tag=666;
    [cell addSubview:b1Lab5];

    b1Lab6=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(210,49,90,50)];

    NSString *st13 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"5 YR: %@%%",[[sortedArray mutableArrayValueForKey:fiveYear]objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]];
    b1Lab6.text=st13;
    b1Lab6.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    b1Lab6.numberOfLines = 0;
    b1Lab6.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:13];
    b1Lab2.tag=777;
    [cell addSubview:b1Lab6];

    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
}
else if(flag == YES)
{
    b1Lab1=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20,2,200,40)];

    // NSString *stri = [title objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    b1Lab1.text=[companyName objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    b1Lab1.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    b1Lab1.numberOfLines = 0;
    b1Lab1.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:13];
    b1Lab1.tag = 111;
    [cell addSubview:b1Lab1];

    b1Lab2=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(222,12,80,20)];
    NSString *st = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"YTD %@%%",[ytdRate objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]];
    b1Lab2.textAlignment=NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    b1Lab2.text=st;
    b1Lab2.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    b1Lab2.numberOfLines = 0;
    b1Lab2.tag = 222;
    b1Lab2.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:13];

    NSString *tem = [ytdRate objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    //    NSArray *testItems = [tem componentsSeparatedByString:@"%"];
    //
    //    NSDecimalNumber *value = [testItems objectAtIndex:0];

    float tempr = [tem floatValue];
    if(tempr <0){
        b1Lab2.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"val_red_80x20.png"]];
    }
    else{
        b1Lab2.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"val_green_80x20.png"]];
    }

    [cell addSubview:b1Lab2];

    b1Lab3=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20,35,180,20)];
    NSString *st1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Net Asset Value Per Share"];
    b1Lab3.text=st1;
    b1Lab3.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:13];
    b1Lab3.tag = 333;
    [cell addSubview:b1Lab3];

    b1Lab8=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200,35,95,20)];
    b1Lab8.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
    NSString *st10 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [netAsset objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]];
    b1Lab8.text=st10;
    b1Lab8.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:13];
    b1Lab8.tag = 444;
    [cell addSubview:b1Lab8];



    b1Lab4 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20,49,90,50)];

    NSString *st11 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"1 YR: %@%%",[oneYearValue objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]];
    b1Lab4.text=st11;
    b1Lab4.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    b1Lab4.numberOfLines = 0;
    b1Lab4.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:13];
    b1Lab4.tag = 555;
    [cell addSubview:b1Lab4];

    b1Lab5=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(115,49,90,50)];

    NSString *st12 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"3 YR: %@%%",[threeYearValue objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]];
    b1Lab5.text=st12;
    b1Lab5.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    b1Lab5.numberOfLines = 0;
    b1Lab5.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:13];
    b1Lab5.tag = 666;
    [cell addSubview:b1Lab5];

    b1Lab6=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(210,49,90,50)];

    NSString *st13 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"5 YR: %@%%",[fiveYearValue objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]];
    b1Lab6.text=st13;
    b1Lab6.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    b1Lab6.numberOfLines = 0;
    b1Lab6.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:13];
    b1Lab6.tag = 777;
    [cell addSubview:b1Lab6];

    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
}

[cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];

return cell;}
```

Comment: for flag == NO condition its not working

Comment: ya but for if(flag == NO) condition its not working

Comment: how can it be my problem when i just display normal data fetch from server it works but when i sort according to condition the display it gets overlap (as u can see for both if condition code is same but aaray data sending is different)

Comment: NO its not working on commenting that code

Answer (score 0):

`tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` means that you're requesting a UITableViewCell object of a certain type (identifier), and you'll get either a new or old one depending on whether or not a cell with your identifier has been created yet.

Your code requests a set of table cells and fills them with UILabels. When you scroll, your table view requests more table cells. At this point, since some cells of this type have already been created, you're getting the old objects - the old table cells with UILabels already in them - and then creating *more* UILabels within these cells. This is why they overlap.

You could stop using reusable cells, and simply create a new UITableViewCell for each table cell, however this is not recommended. This method would use significantly more memory as the number of table cells increases, which is the problem that reusable cells are intended to overcome. A more detailed explanation is available in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2928873/iphone-dequeuereusablecellwithidentifier-usage/6906286).

Instead, what you should do is simply clear all of the content from the reusable cells that you retrieve, ensuring that your cell is clear of any previously created content when you create your UILabels again. Adding the following code to your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` (after you've retrieved a reusable cell) method will do the trick:

```
for(UIView *view in [cell subviews])
    [view removeFromSuperview];
```

Comment: for(UIView *view in [cell subviews])
    [view removeFromSuperview]; and create a new UITableViewCell for each table cell both logic did not work

Answer (score -1):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];}
  for (UIView *v [cell.contenetView subviews]{
    [v removefromSuperView];}

 ******* Change code  *********

    if (flag == NO) {

    b1Lab1=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20,2,200,40)];

    // NSString *stri = [title objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    b1Lab1.text=[[sortedArray mutableArrayValueForKey:companyNam]objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    b1Lab1.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    b1Lab1.numberOfLines = 0;
    b1Lab1.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:13];
    [cell addSubview:b1Lab1];

    b1Lab2=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(222,12,80,20)];
    NSString *st = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"YTD %@%%",[[sortedArray mutableArrayValueForKey:ytd]objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]];
    b1Lab2.textAlignment=NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    b1Lab2.text=st;
    b1Lab2.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    b1Lab2.numberOfLines = 0;
    b1Lab2.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:13];

    NSString *tem = [[sortedArray mutableArrayValueForKey:ytd]objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
//    NSArray *testItems = [tem componentsSeparatedByString:@"%"];
//    
//    NSDecimalNumber *value = [testItems objectAtIndex:0];

    float tempr = [tem floatValue];
    if(tempr <0){
        b1Lab2.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"val_red_80x20.png"]];
    }
    else{
        b1Lab2.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"val_green_80x20.png"]];
    }

    [cell addSubview:b1Lab2];

    b1Lab3=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20,35,180,20)];
    NSString *st1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Net Asset Value Per Share"];
    b1Lab3.text=st1;
    b1Lab3.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:13];
    [cell addSubview:b1Lab3];

        b1Lab8=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200,35,95,20)];
        b1Lab8.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
        NSString *st10 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[sortedArray mutableArrayValueForKey:netVal]objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]];
        b1Lab8.text=st10;
        b1Lab8.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:13];
        [cell addSubview:b1Lab8];

    b1Lab4 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20,49,90,50)];

    NSString *st11 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"1 YR: %@%%",[[sortedArray mutableArrayValueForKey:oneYear]objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]];
    b1Lab4.text=st11;
    b1Lab4.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    b1Lab4.numberOfLines = 0;
    b1Lab4.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:13];
    [cell addSubview:b1Lab4];

    b1Lab5=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(115,49,90,50)];

    NSString *st12 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"3 YR: %@%%",[[sortedArray mutableArrayValueForKey:threeYear]objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]];
    b1Lab5.text=st12;
    b1Lab5.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    b1Lab5.numberOfLines = 0;
    b1Lab5.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:13];
    [cell addSubview:b1Lab5];

    b1Lab6=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(210,49,90,50)];

    NSString *st13 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"5 YR: %@%%",[[sortedArray mutableArrayValueForKey:fiveYear]objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]];
    b1Lab6.text=st13;
    b1Lab6.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    b1Lab6.numberOfLines = 0;
    b1Lab6.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:13];
    [cell addSubview:b1Lab6];

    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    }
    else if(flag == YES)
    {
        b1Lab1=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20,2,200,40)];

        // NSString *stri = [title objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
        b1Lab1.text=[companyName objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
        b1Lab1.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
        b1Lab1.numberOfLines = 0;
        b1Lab1.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:13];
        [cell addSubview:b1Lab1];

        b1Lab2=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(222,12,80,20)];
        NSString *st = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"YTD %@%%",[ytdRate objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]];
        b1Lab2.textAlignment=NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        b1Lab2.text=st;
        b1Lab2.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
        b1Lab2.numberOfLines = 0;
        b1Lab2.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:13];

        NSString *tem = [ytdRate objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
        //    NSArray *testItems = [tem componentsSeparatedByString:@"%"];
        //
        //    NSDecimalNumber *value = [testItems objectAtIndex:0];

        float tempr = [tem floatValue];
        if(tempr <0){
            b1Lab2.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"val_red_80x20.png"]];
        }
        else{
            b1Lab2.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"val_green_80x20.png"]];
        }

        [cell addSubview:b1Lab2];

        b1Lab3=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20,35,180,20)];
        NSString *st1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Net Asset Value Per Share"];
        b1Lab3.text=st1;
        b1Lab3.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:13];
        [cell addSubview:b1Lab3];

        b1Lab8=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200,35,95,20)];
        b1Lab8.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
        NSString *st10 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [netAsset objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]];
        b1Lab8.text=st10;
        b1Lab8.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:13];
        [cell addSubview:b1Lab8];



        b1Lab4 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20,49,90,50)];

        NSString *st11 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"1 YR: %@%%",[oneYearValue objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]];
        b1Lab4.text=st11;
        b1Lab4.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
        b1Lab4.numberOfLines = 0;
        b1Lab4.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:13];
        [cell addSubview:b1Lab4];

        b1Lab5=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(115,49,90,50)];

        NSString *st12 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"3 YR: %@%%",[threeYearValue objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]];
        b1Lab5.text=st12;
        b1Lab5.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
        b1Lab5.numberOfLines = 0;
        b1Lab5.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:13];
        [cell addSubview:b1Lab5];

        b1Lab6=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(210,49,90,50)];

        NSString *st13 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"5 YR: %@%%",[fiveYearValue objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]];
        b1Lab6.text=st13;
        b1Lab6.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
        b1Lab6.numberOfLines = 0;
        b1Lab6.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:13];
        [cell addSubview:b1Lab6];

        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    }

    [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];

    return cell;
}
```

**NEW UPDATED ANSWER**

```
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:nil];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault 
reuseIdentifier:nil];
    }
```

Comment: Is this helpful to you?

Comment: i tried this but problem did not solved

Comment: @naresh, I updated my code. Re-try this. change `v` instead of `vin` in for loop.

Comment: that i have already changed but still not working

Comment: @naresh, paste your code in pastebin.com

Comment: @naresh, see my new updated answer in which `set the reuserIdentifier as nil.`

Comment: no idea of down vote as i have not given

Comment: @SBM, I know but I just want to send the message which is given down vote because some stupid people can't sustain in competition, so they are trying to pull the others legs.