# UITableView Repeating Content

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I know this is an age old problem, but I have a little twist on it this time.

As the title says, my UITableView is repeating content. In this case, the background colour changes on a cell it isn't supposed to when scrolling it off and back on screen.

I understand this is probably due to reusing cells, but my issue is I can't just give each cell a unique cell identifier, as I have built my cell in my Storyboard, which requires it to be typed in there.

So how can I get around this problem, while keeping my cell designed inside my storyboard?

A little code:

```
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";
        SLDetailCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

        if (!cell)
        {
            cell = [[SLDetailCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
        }

    [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor slateBackgroundGrey]]; //Set standard background colour
    [cell.titleLbl setText:[self.tableTitles objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]; //cell titles from an array (static data I made)

    //This will occur for each cell, here are two examples
    if ([cell.titleLbl.text isEqualToString:@"Aircraft"])
    {
        NSString *detailText = @"";
        if (!self.flight.aircraft) detailText = @"N/A";
        else detailText = self.flight.aircraft.name;
        [cell.detailLbl setText:detailText];
    }
    if ([cell.titleLbl.text isEqualToString:@"Delete"])
    {
        UIView *containerView = [cell.titleLbl superview];
        [containerView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor triggerRed]];
        [cell.titleLbl setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        [cell.disclosureIndicator setHidden:YES];
        [cell.detailLbl setText:@""];
    }
```

In the case of the delete cell I change the colour properties of the cell.

Subclassing `prepareForReuse` to reset cell data fails to stop repeating data, as does setting the colour in every individual cell if statement (like you see above).

Thanks.

Comment: Where's your code for setting the background color?

Comment: Oh, and what's the twist? This sounds like the same issue everyone has with improper reuse.

Comment: Every solution I have seen, dozens and dozens of them all resolve this by using unique cell identifiers, however when your using a storyboard this is useless. Thats all, just that I'm using a storyboard :)

Comment: If people are using unique reuse identifiers just because the colors are different then they are doing it wrong. Again, post your relevant code for setting the background so we can show you the proper way.

Comment: Ok I've added all the code needed (hopefully), fingers crossed that sheds some more light.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever you return a cell, reused or not, you must configure all of the cell attributes. Otherwise, you get in a situation where some attributes get hung over from last time around. This applies whether the cell is created from a storyboard or otherwise, it's a cell reuse issue, nothing more.

Comment: You should get a hugged badge, for being virtually bro-hugged by another user.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you have a custom `UITableViewCell` subclass. You can override the `prepareForReuse` method in that class and reset the background color (or really anything else you want reset) in the same.

Make sure you call `[super prepareForReuse]` in your implementation.

Answer (score 0):

From Apple docs:

> The table view's delegate in tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: should
>   always reset all content when reusing a cell.

Source:
[UITableViewCell Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableViewCell/prepareForReuse)

So be sure to set your background color there.

Hope it helps.

Comment: The first thing I do after initialising the cell is set the background colour. Then in the case that it is a 'Delete' cell, I change the colour. Or do I need to set the colour in every if case that I have for each cell?

Comment: If the "Delete" cell has the same reuse ID as the next cell then you should always set appropriate background color. Other solution could be to have a separate reuse ID for the "Delete" cell.

Answer (score 0):

This SO answer contains answer why and how to use UITableViewCell dequeue. When you know that you'll know why content repeats: [iPhone - dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2928873/iphone-dequeuereusablecellwithidentifier-usage)