# Why do both UITableViewCell and UITableView have methods to create new cells?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

The [UITableViewCell Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Uikit/reference/UITableViewCell_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableViewCell/initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:), regarding `initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:` says:

> Initializes a table cell with a style and a reuse identifier and
>   returns it to the caller.

But in the [UITableView Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uitableview_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier:) `registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier:` says:

> Registers a class for use in creating new table cells.

Both methods `alloc`/`init` new cells, but what is the difference between the two? And why are there two methods for creating new cell objects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two methods do different things:

- `registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier:` works in tandem with `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:`. Registration tells the table which class to instantiate for a particular reuse identifier. You can call it more than once passing different classes for different identifiers. Calls of `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` will instantiate the class that you specify.
- `initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:` method, on the other hand, lets you make a table cell directly, when `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` returns `nil`. Providing a reuse identifier lets the table recycle your cell when it scrolls off the screen.

Comment: but I have seen many places where initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier: is used with dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2928873/iphone-dequeuereusablecellwithidentifier-usage please view second answer with 17 votes. So now whats the difference between two methods?

Comment: @S.J You use one or the other: if you register a class, `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` never returns `nil`, so the `if(cell == nil)` branch from the answer would not get entered.

Comment: sorry i didn't get this point "so the if(cell == nil) branch from the answer would not get entered". And can we use initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier: with UITableviewCell subclass?

Comment: @S.J If you call `registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier:` with a specific reuse identifier, calling `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` will always return a non-null cell. In the answer at the link in your comment on line 7 a `cell` is dequeued, and on line 9 it is checked for `nil` before calling `initWithFrame:reuseIdentifier:` on lines 12, 16, and 20. If you register a class for reuse identifier, the check on line 9 would never succeed.

Comment: @S.J If you would like to use `initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:` with a subclass, the subclass should override `initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:` initializer, and call `super` inside the implementation.

Comment: initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier: is old or manual way And registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier: is new or automated way right?