# Getting section index path and editing section header

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, tableview

I will just give you a short-explanation of my question. I have a text field and a button and a grouped tableView. Whenever I want to touch my button, I want to take text of text field and create a section in table, and assign the text to the section which is just created. I know we can handle that in a row with IndexPath but couldn't see a solution for this yet. Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried so far (show code) and explain in detail what it does wrong.

Comment: Where is the code ??? i can't anything !!!

Comment: I added it, patient please :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make an Array:

```
var sections: Array <String>!
```

Initialize it in initilzer or ViewDidLoad

```
self.sections = Array();
```

Override these two methods

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
return self.sections[section]
}
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
return self.sections.count;
}
```

On button action, use following code

```
 @IBAction func addItem(sender: AnyObject) {
        self.sections.append(self.textField.text)
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

Comment: thank you very much. I got a question what does "override" in front of func,  do actually?

Comment: And I realized that, only thing I actually forgot was appending :( On my very first code. Thank you!

Comment: Kindly vote up if you like my answer :) @MertKarakus

Comment: Well, I just had enough rep. You're lucky mister :D

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code I tried for row(which is worked) and section:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        var cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")

        cell.textLabel?.text = myArray[indexPath.row]


        return cell


    }


    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String?{

        //Whenever an item is added, every sector will get an identifier. So with that, they can match the array's index.




        return nil

    }
    override func sectionIndexTitlesForTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> [AnyObject]! {





        return nil

    }
```

Comment: On another note, you should deque cells not make it everytime  cellForRowAtIndexPath  is called.
Replace UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "Cell") with tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

Comment: what is the different, to be exact? @AbubakrDar

Comment: Take a look at this Answer, Hope you will understand

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2928873/iphone-dequeuereusablecellwithidentifier-usage