# tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier VS tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

My Xcode is 7.1. Emulator is iPhone6.
Normally I use `dequeueResuableCellWithIdentifier`, but this time I got a problem.
**My Problem is :**
It does not clear out my `orangeColor()` after selecting new row. But print line deselecting `indexPath` is correct.
**My Solution is :**
I changed from 
`let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("MyCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MyCell;`
to
`let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! MyCell;`
Then it solve my problem. The background color is `clearColor()`.

**Here are my files :**
MyCell.swift :

```
import UIKit

class MyCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var myLabel : UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var myWebView : UIWebView!;
    //@IBOutlet weak var myView : UIView!;
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code.
    }

    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

**ViewController.swift :**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableViewObject: UITableView!

    var fruits = ["Apple", "Banana","Cherry", "Durian", "ElderBerry"];
    var selectedIndexPath : NSIndexPath?;
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.tableViewObject.delegate = self;
        self.tableViewObject.dataSource = self;
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
        return fruits.count;
    }
    func loadCellContent(acell : UITableViewCell, indexPath : NSIndexPath, color: UIColor){
        let cell = acell as! MyCell;
        cell.myLabel.text = String(UnicodeScalar(65 + indexPath.row));
        cell.myWebView.loadHTMLString(fruits[indexPath.row], baseURL: nil);
        cell.myWebView.scrollView.bounces = false;
        cell.myWebView.scrollView.scrollEnabled = false;
        cell.myWebView.userInteractionEnabled = false;
        cell.backgroundColor = color;
        cell.myLabel.backgroundColor = color;
        cell.myWebView.backgroundColor = color;
    }
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("MyCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MyCell;
        self.loadCellContent(cell, indexPath: indexPath, color: UIColor.clearColor());
        return cell;
    }

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int{
        return 1;
    }
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        //let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("MyCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MyCell;
        let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! MyCell;
        self.loadCellContent(cell, indexPath: indexPath, color : UIColor.orangeColor());
    }
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        //let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("MyCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MyCell;
        let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! MyCell;
        self.loadCellContent(cell, indexPath: indexPath,color: UIColor.clearColor());
        print("Hellos", indexPath.row);

    }
}
```

**My questions are :**
1. What is a major different between method `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifer` and `cellForRowAtIndexPath`?
2. When to use first one or second one and how do I know it?
This time I use trial/error from one tutorial to one another.

**Update :**
My background is Physics and little bit Computer Science. Please do not get angry on my naive question or so on.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iPhone - dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier usage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2928873/iphone-dequeuereusablecellwithidentifier-usage)

Comment: `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifer` should only be used in the implementation of `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik Thank you for your searching. I am now get more understanding on `dequeueReusableCellWithIndentifier()`. My understanding is `dequeue` will reuse the memory, but the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is not reuse the memory. Am I right? I still not clear why the 2nd one works, but first one is not.

Comment: @rmaddy Sorry I don't understand. Could you please explain me with example of it?

Comment: @rmaddy. I got it now! Thank you :)

Comment: Please follow this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2928873/iphone-dequeuereusablecellwithidentifier-usage

Comment: I might suggest renaming `loadCellContent` to `loadContentForCell` because, by convention, the last noun in the method name refers to whatever the first parameter is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tableview tries not to have instances of cell objects for all the indexpaths at all times in memory:

- 'dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifer' recycles a cell or creates it and should be called in 'cellForRow...'. This **always returns a cell instance**, either a new one or one that was no longer visible previously. You prepare the cell for display after that.
- 'cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell? // **returns nil if** cell is not visible or index path is out of range' this doesn't create cells, only gives you access to them. I think it should be avoided as much as possible to prevent accidental leaks and other interference with the tableView.

About your 'setSelected' problem:

- it's good ideea to implement prepare for reuse (set all values to defaults) in the cell class.
- you shouldn't need to load cell content again in 'didSelectRow' (the user just tapped on it at that point, so it's loaded)
- you may need to change between orange/clear colors in the cell's 'setSelected'

Comment: Your comment that `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifer` **always returns a cell instance** is simply not true. It can return `nil` under many circumstances.

Comment: @rmaddy - Minor refinement on your observation: If you use `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:indexPath:` (which the OP used in his code sample and to which Andrei is presumably referring ... he should clarify), it always returns a cell instance. On the other hand, if you are referring to the older `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:`, that can return `nil` if there is no class/nib/prototype associated with that identifier and if there isn't a cell in the reuse queue.

Comment: @Rob Good clarification. I should have been more clear that I was referring to the `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` method and not the one that also takes an index path.

Answer (score 2):

These two methods serve different purposes.

- The `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:indexPath:` instantiates a new cell if necessary, but will reuse a cell that has previously scrolled off the screen if one is available.

  You call this method only from `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.
- The `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method (not to be confused with the similarly named `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method) does not instantiate a new cell, but rather is only used for grabbing a reference to a previously instantiated cell that is currently visible. If the cell is not visible (e.g., has scrolled off screen), then this returns `nil`.

  You use this method in methods such as `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` and `tableView:didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:`, because you're simply trying to grab a reference to an existing cell, not instantiate a new one.

--

Note, in your code sample, you are calling your `loadCellContent` from not only `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, but also `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` and `tableView:didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:`, too. I'd advise separating the initial configuration of the cell (e.g., `loadCellContent`, which you'll only call from `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`) from the adjusting of the background color (which you'll do in `didSelect...` and `didDeselect...`). These latter two methods generally would not reconfigure the whole cell again, but rather just update the background color (or perform whatever adornment appropriate to show the selection).

Also you want to make sure that `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` checks to see if the cell is selected when configuring the background color. It's possible that the user may select a cell, scroll it off screen, and then scroll it back on screen, in which case `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` must check to see if the cell is selected or not in order to set the background color.

For example:

```
// MARK: Cell configuration

func loadContentForCell(cell: UITableViewCell, indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    // do whatever you need here; I'm just going to set the `textLabel`
    cell.textLabel?.text = "Row \(indexPath.row)"
}

func updateBackgroundColorForCell(cell: UITableViewCell?) {
    cell?.contentView.backgroundColor = cell?.selected == true ? UIColor.redColor() : UIColor.whiteColor()
}

// MARK: UITableViewDataSource

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 100
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
    
    loadContentForCell(cell, indexPath: indexPath)
    updateBackgroundColorForCell(cell)
    
    return cell
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)
    updateBackgroundColorForCell(cell)
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)
    updateBackgroundColorForCell(cell)
}
```

Comment: Thank you. From now on. I will follow your sample format it is clear for me how to implement the functions :]